# java - Hibernate doesn't read object from database correctly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am having some issues according `Hibernate`.

I have a more or less complex object structure that I want to save / load using the Hibernate EntityManager (version 4.3.5.Final). I managed to save it, but if I attempt to read the obejct, only the PK will be read. The EntityManager's find method returns null even with the correct PK so I am using its getReference method.

I still have troubles using the correct relationship (ManyToOne and such) so I most likely made a mistake there and I guess that is causing the problem.
Anyways.

My question is: How do i persist an object structure like this using `Hibernate`?

Here are the POJOs i am using:

**EDIT**: Updated the Code

CalculationList:

```
@Entity(name = "calculation")
public class CalculationList implements EntityList {

@Id
private Date created;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Product> products;

public CalculationList(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
    this.products = new LinkedList<>();
}

public CalculationList(Date created, List<Product> products) {
    this.created = created;
    this.products = products;
}

public CalculationList() {
}

public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}

public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(List<Product> entities) {
    this.products = entities;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CalculationList{" +
            "created=" + created +
            ", products=" + products +
            '}';
}
}
```

CalulatorEntity:

```
@Entity(name = "calculator_entity")
public class CalculatorEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
private int id;

private CalculatorEntityType type;

private String name;

private int number;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Product product;

public CalculatorEntity(CalculatorEntityType type) {
    this.type = type;
}

protected CalculatorEntity() {
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public CalculatorEntityType getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(CalculatorEntityType type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public enum CalculatorEntityType {
    GAS_PUMP, DELIVERY_BILL;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CalculatorEntity{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", type=" + type +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", product=" + product +
            ", number=" + number +
            '}';
}
}
```

Product:

```
@Entity(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

@Id
private int id;

private String name;

private ProductType type;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CalculatorEntity> entities;

public Product(String name, ProductType type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.entities = new LinkedList<>();
}

/**
 * JPA - Konstruktor
 */
public Product() {
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ProductType getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(ProductType type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public List<CalculatorEntity> getEntities() {
    return entities;
}

public void setEntities(List<CalculatorEntity> entities) {
    this.entities = entities;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", type=" + type +
            ", entities=" + entities +
            '}';
}

public enum ProductType {

    FUEL("Treibstoff"), OIL("Öl"), OTHER("Verschiedenes");

    private String name;

    private ProductType(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `@OneToMany` mapping with the wrong entity, instead of mapping `Product` class you are mapping `CalculationList` class, move the following configuration:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CalculatorEntity> entities;
```

to the `Product` class.

Comment: Alright, thank you I changed it. I changed the code a bit, so now the CalculationList has a List of Products and the Product has a List of CalculatorEntities. When i read the object now i get: `CalculationList{created=2015-05-08 10:44:05.0, products=[Product{id=0, name='Benzin', type=FUEL, entities=[]}]}`. There is still something wrong with the entities. Any ideas why?

Comment: do you want to have a list of products in the `CalculationList` ?

Comment: Alright, got it now: I forgot to initialize the Product in CalculatorEntity

Comment: Try to specify join collumn in your @ManyToOne relation on the CalculatorEntity side of the relation